# Why does CloudBlobClient.BaseUri add a trailing slash (sometimes)?

Tags: c#, uri

I am starting to think this is a bug but I'm not certain. Here is my situation.

**Setup Information**

I have a website that allows uploads to an Azure Storage Blob, and the endpoints are specified in the web config. The base web config contains

```
<blobEndpoint value="http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1" />
```

And the testing server web config contains

```
<blobEndpoint value="https://myazureaccount.blob.core.windows.net" xdt:Transform="Replace" />
```

I have a custom configuration handler to retrieve the value from the web config like so

```
[ConfigurationProperty("blobEndpoint", IsRequired = true)]
public StringConfigurationElement BlobEndpoint
{
    get
    {
        return (StringConfigurationElement)base["blobEndpoint"];
    }
    set
    {
        base["blobEndpoint"] = value;
    }
}
```

I obtain a reference to the storage account like this

```
StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey credentials = 
     new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey(
                     CloudStorageAccount.CloudStorageAccountName,
                     CloudStorageAccount.CloudStorageAccountKey);

this.cloudStorageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, 
                     CloudStorageAccount.BlobEndpoint, 
                     CloudStorageAccount.QueueEndpoint, 
                     CloudStorageAccount.TableEndpoint);
```

Then obtain a reference to the cloud blob client like this

```
this.cloudBlobClient = this.cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
```

**Issue at hand**

This is where I start to get differing results.

If I use the storage emulator endpoint (`http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1`) and make this call

```
this.cloudBlobClient.BaseUri
```

the return value is `http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1`

However, if I use my actual account endpoint (`https://myazureaccount.blob.core.windows.net`) and make the same call, the return value is `https://myazureaccount.blob.core.windows.net/`.

Notice the trailing slash at the end. Why **isn't** that present when using a storage emulator uri? Or why **is** it present when using a real account uri?

**Update**

I stepped through newing up a Uri from the web config setting and this was the output of each case

```
{https://myazureaccount.blob.core.windows.net/}
    AbsolutePath: "/"
    AbsoluteUri: "https://myazureaccount.blob.core.windows.net/"
    Authority: "myazureaccount.blob.core.windows.net"
    DnsSafeHost: "myazureaccount.blob.core.windows.net"
    Fragment: ""
    Host: "myazureaccount.blob.core.windows.net"
    HostNameType: Dns
    IsAbsoluteUri: true
    IsDefaultPort: true
    IsFile: false
    IsLoopback: false
    IsUnc: false
    LocalPath: "/"
    OriginalString: "https://myazureaccount.blob.core.windows.net"
    PathAndQuery: "/"
    Port: 443
    Query: ""
    Scheme: "https"
    Segments: {string[1]}
    UserEscaped: false
    UserInfo: ""


{http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1}
    AbsolutePath: "/devstoreaccount1"
    AbsoluteUri: "http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1"
    Authority: "127.0.0.1:10000"
    DnsSafeHost: "127.0.0.1"
    Fragment: ""
    Host: "127.0.0.1"
    HostNameType: IPv4
    IsAbsoluteUri: true
    IsDefaultPort: false
    IsFile: false
    IsLoopback: true
    IsUnc: false
    LocalPath: "/devstoreaccount1"
    OriginalString: "http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1"
    PathAndQuery: "/devstoreaccount1"
    Port: 10000
    Query: ""
    Scheme: "http"
    Segments: {string[2]}
    UserEscaped: false
    UserInfo: ""
```

And it seems that this is actually an issue with the `Uri` class and not related to `CloudBlobClient`. I have updated the tags appropriately.

Comment: Can you not use the URI Class to return the `AbsolutePath` it should return a string without the trailing `/`

Comment: Negative. The parameters required for `new CloudStorageAccount` are credentials + uris

Comment: The part that hurts is that the behavior is different given the input, even though the format of the input is the same (it's initialized without a trailing slash). If it were consistent and always added a trailing slash I wouldn't have a problem handling for it.

Comment: look at this link here some of the endPoints they add a `/` at the end of the URI http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/

Comment: It looks like it's actually related to the Uri class. I updated my question.

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with URI Class.. could it be this line 
`PathAndQuery:` are you familiar with testing using the `URI` I could post you a simple example that you can test in the same code before you call the Methods that you are calling currently.

Comment: That's absolutely it. I wasn't thinking of the `devstoreaccount01` portion as a path parameter but rather I was thinking about it as part of the base uri. Thanks :)

Comment: So the problem was in the `PathAndQuery: "/"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the only thing that could causing that would be the

```
PathAndQuery: "/"
```

Remove that and things should workout just fine.
Also if you need to Test the URI Class I wrote you something really quick that you can use that would save you a lot of time and headache in the future for testing if the `URI Class` returns the correct Host`

```
var uriList = new List<string>()
    {
        "https://myazureaccount.blob.core.windows.net",
        "https://myazureaccount1.blob.core.windows.net",
        "https://myazureaccount2.blob.core.windows.net"
    };

var holdList = uriList.Select(uriName => new Uri(uriName)).Select(uri => uri.Host).ToList();
```